# Shrinking widgets during resize in Tkinter (can I decide shrinkage behavior?)

Tags: python, tkinter, window-resize

I am designing a GUI in Python/Tkinter. Resizing the root frame makes the geometry controller adapt and resize the widgets in the GUI according to the room available, up to here everything's fine.

BUT... One of the widgets that gets shrunk first is a left-justified label. I would like it to start disappearing from the right side, instead Tkinter reduces it from left and right at the same time.

Here is a sample code to replicate the situation:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
my_font = ("Consolas", 12)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1\nGoes on the Left", justify="left", font=my_font, bg='cyan')
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 2\nGoes on the Right", justify="left", font=my_font, bg='magenta')
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 3 - Goes in the middle\n(During a resize, this shrinks first)",
                  justify="left", font=my_font, bg='orange')

label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
label2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
label3.pack(side=tk.LEFT) # packed last, so it gets reduced first during a resize

root.mainloop()
```

And here is a picture of what happens with that same code: [resize in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk94M.png)

Is there a way to tell the geometry controller how to reduce the widgets during window resize?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a simple configuration addition to label3. Add the anchor='w' attribute, and it will behave as you described. The label will shrink from the right only.

```
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 3 - Goes in the middle\n(During a resize, this shrinks first)", justify="left", font=my_font, bg='orange', anchor='w')
```